# Clearing the Cache in Coldfusion Production server

Tags: coldfusion

I am using CFMX and there is an issue (variable "yy" is undefined in "yyfiling")thats a show stopper , on the production.

I am promoting corrections to it but they do not seem to show up on  the server.

I want to resort to clearing the Server cache so that my promoted code can take effect.

The CFAdmin production template was cached (Trusted Cache turned on), so wanna turn it off Trusted Cache and clear template cache.
Should do that ASAP.

So was wondering it will effect the main site?
ANY PRECAUTIONS?

Answer (score 2):

You can programmatically clear the ColdFusion template cache of all templates or a specific  template.  Ray Camden has documented it here:

Clearing individual files from template cache with AdminAPI
http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2008/6/19/Clearing-individual-filesfolders-from-ColdFusion-templates-cache

ColdFusion Admin API and template cache
http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2007/6/7/ColdFusion-8-Admin-API-and-Trusted-Cache

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it in development and seeing if anything adverse happens. That is what a good development (or better yet QA) environment is for.

Answer (score 0):

USE SVN/GIT, save an existing copy of the code, before you do that.  In case your new code brings in even more critical bugs, revert back to existing one at once.

Comment: ok, u know what i mean.  As long as you have a source control... prepare to revert if something blizzard happens. :)

Answer (score 0):

I clear the cache all the time. The only difference you'll see is that the first time a coldfusion template is requested, it'll add a bit of time to the request due to the compilation coldfusion must do under the hood. this will be a one-time hit.

Fear not.