# Inconsistent 'Cannot find CFML template for custom tag' error

Tags: coldfusion

I have a CF9 site set up locally on OSX Snow Leopard, and it's started to behave very strangely - probably about 1 out of every 5 times I load any page in the site, it will throw a 'Cannot find CFML template for custom tag' error.  I just refresh the page and then everything works fine.  It can happen on any page, but it never happens consistently with any one page.  Furthermore, this doesn't happen at all on the live server when the code is checked in through SVN, so I figure it has to be some kind of configuration problem on my local instance. I can still do my work, but it's pretty annoying having to refresh pages ALL the time.  Has anyone run into similar difficulties?

Comment: Sounds like code that's running only part of the time (ie. every x requests), which is not completely unheard of. I assume you've verified that the CustomTags directory is correctly set up, and that the CustomTag in question is in place, tested, verified--you've created a one-off standalone page that can also call the tag and it works as well--that sort of thing?

Comment: Yes, the custom tag paths and everything are correct - the tag in question is actually located in application.cfm, so it is the first custom tag that each request will encounter, and is present in every pageload. It's almost like the CF Server just forgets where the custom tags live 20% of the time :-\

Comment: I'm unconvinced. Is it safe/can you supply the contents of the Application.cfm in this question's detail, highlighting the call to the CustomTag in question?

Comment: Is your live server also Mac OS X? Have your custom tags folders be created as a checkout or an export from SVN (ie - are the .svn folders present under your custom tag folders)?

Comment: Yes, the .svn folder is present in the Custom Tag folder... as far as the contents of application.cfm, I can't post the entirety of it, but here is the redacted version from the beginning of the file to the tag that triggers the failure (below)

Comment: *sorry about the formatting, I'm not sure how to make it keep the linebreaks and indentations.`<!--- Declare Application Settings --->    <cfapplication name="appname"
  clientmanagement="yes"
  setclientcookies="yes"
  sessionmanagement="yes">

 <!--- copy the FORM and URL variables to the ATTRIBUTES scope --->
 <cf_FormURL2Attributes>`

Comment: @ChrisBarcroft: Please edit your question with that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `<cfmodule template="pathTo/yourTag.cfm">` rather than `<cf_yourtag>`, so you can specify the exact location of the template (in case the server is getting confused as to where it resides).

FYI, this is based on a tip from Raymond Camden's blog post: http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2006/8/17/ColdFusion-Custom-Tag-Tips

Comment: You're on to something... it's still throwing errors 20% of the time, but the errors have changed to 'Data source could not be found' instead (even though the DS works just fine the other 80% again).  Is there a similar principle that can be applied to the datasource?

Comment: Presumably, your datasource is set as a variable.  Take a look at see where that variable is being set, and if it might be set differently under different conditions.  One other thing I would verify is that you are really using the correct version of your template, now that you are more certain as to which one you're using.  It could be you were previously using a different template, that was using the proper datasource, and now that you're using this one, you need to update the value.

Comment: Well, since you solved the initial question and the new issue seems to be related but different, I'll go ahead and mark you correct and open a new question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Chris, odd that I should run into your question now, as this just started happening to me last night. I have all of my CF errors being emailed to me, and I am seeing that similar problems are happening across multiple sites that all run the same software, some of which haven't been touched in a long time. That got me thinking, it's probably a corrupt compiled template in the CF cache. You can recompile the template by making a slight change to it, say add an extra line or a comment or something, then access the site again. Or, purge the whole cache and let CF rebuild everything, which is likely what I'll do since who knows what else might be affected.

[Clearing the Cache in Coldfusion Production server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432291/clearing-the-cache-in-coldfusion-production-server)

Comment: This didn't help me unfortunately.. still looking for answers.